# Companion AI with NavMeshAgent causing jittery movement on the X-Axis

Tags: unity, ai, navmesh

I'm trying to do a companion AI that follows around my player but with a certain distance.
I first tried to self-program the movement behavior. but realized quickly that a `NavMeshAgent` offers more simple solutions to what I'm trying to achieve.

Now the problem is that my AI doesn't follow around smoothly. It's surely not because of the camera, since my player and my enemy AIs do not have these jittery movement.
My script is as simple as it can get:

```
private Transform target;
private NavMeshAgent agent;

public Animator partnerAnim;
public GameObject player;

private void Start()
{
    // set target to player transform
    target = GameManager.GM.playerMachine.transform;
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Determining wether to play the walk animation or not
    partnerAnim.SetFloat("normalizedSpeed", Mathf.Clamp01(agent.velocity.magnitude));

    agent.SetDestination(target.position);
}
```

My stopping distance is at 2 and my speed is at 3.5.
No matter how I change these values, the jittery movement won't change.

I also have a rigidbody attached to my `NavMeshAgent`, and I made sure to turn on `isKinematic`, and I also removed it to check if that solves the problem, but it didn't.

The weird thing is that it only seems to be a problem when moving along the X-Axis. When I move on the Z-Axis only, my partner is following my player smoothly (I'm guessing this is because I increase the speed of my player on the Z-Axis, but I don't really see the connection with my problem here. If it would be a speed problem, then lowering the speed on my AI would've fixed this, but it didn't.)

Here are the full `NavMeshAgent` settings:

[image: settings]

Comment: Does it jitter up & down as it moves along the X axis or back & forth along the axis or is it not particularly confined?

Comment: @Pikalek It jitters back & forth heavily, the Y-Axis on my companion is not being influenced at all

Comment: Did you enable interpolation on your rigidbody?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't and I just tried to enable both Interpolate and Extrapolate, which didn't change anything. Here are the settings for my rigidbody: https://imgur.com/a/YD8Ra0G

Comment: Turn on `Auto Breaking` to allow the agent to stop when it approaches the destination point, and also try to add some `Angular Speed` to allow the agent to turn around while it tries to get to the destination.

Comment: @Ermiq I did also try that, and the stuttering is still there, I also can't set angular speed to a value higher than 0 because my characters are 2D in a 3D environment and I don't want to rotate them because of that